# How to pick up data using PowerShell from SharePoint Web Parts

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, powershell-script

We have a manual process at the moment where we have assigned "Content Owners" to out Sites/Sub-Sites. Content Owners, essentially have no greater permissions than regular users, but our Governance Team have assigned them to make the decision as to whether a User can access a resource within the Site Collection or not.

The Content Owner is assigned via a Web Part within the HomePage. Is there a way to pick up this data within a Script. I will be cycling through all Sites/Sub-Sites across my tenant. I know how to go through all Sites/SubSites, but just the data within the specific page isn't available.

[image]

The other method I had in mind, which will require some development, is to create Dummy SharePoint Groups to hold this data. If anyone can think of another way, that would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Another, possibly more sustainable way of doing this is to place this data within the Site Description and pick this data up from there. This is since the Data isn't consistent in the Pages. Some times it is displayed as above and sometimes as plain text.

Comment: Still would love to know if there is possibilities of picking text/web part data would from within Site pages?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to get web part data from a modern page. if so, you could have a try below cmdlets:

- [Get-PnPClientSideComponent](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpclientsidecomponent?view=sharepoint-ps)

Or

```
$page = Get-PnPClientSidePage -Identity Home.aspx    
$webpart = $page.Controls | ? {$_.InstanceId -eq "416a4c58-61fc-4166-aa19-1099fad50545"}  
$webpart.PropertiesJson
```

You may check its data through workbench:

[image]

PnpJs also provided the similar feature:

- https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/clientside-pages/#findcontrol

More reference:

- [Setting JSON Properties for Sharepoint Online Highlighted Content WP using PnP Powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/284135/setting-json-properties-for-sharepoint-online-highlighted-content-wp-using-pnp-p)