# Setting JSON Properties for Sharepoint Online Highlighted Content WP using PnP Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

My requirement is to configure the properties of Highlighted Content WP on Sharepoint online modern page using PnP Powershell.  I have used **Set-PnPClientSideWebPart** command but i am unclear about how should my JSON string should be for [-PropertiesJson ]  option.

I need to add 2 other different sharepoint sites for the Filter criteria with Source as "Select Sites" as shown in screenshot.  Other properties should be as below

1. Type = Documents
2. Document Type - Any
3. Sort By - Most Recent
4. Layout - FilmStrip
5. No of items to show is 100

NOTE :  I need to do this for hundreds of sites and cannot do it manually and looking for automation options.

[image]

Comment: Check [this](https://www.techmikael.com/2017/11/modifying-query-template-for.html) and [this](https://hangconsult.com/2017/11/05/creating-a-new-client-side-page-with-pnp-powershell/). These should give you the basic idea of how to set WebPartProperties using PnP PowerShell for Highlighted content webpart.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON string for a configured Highlighted Content web part can be retrieved using the following script:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url <siteURL>
$page = Get-PnPClientSidePage -Identity <PageName>
$page.controls
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Find the Highlighted Content web part property `InstanceId`, and then you can retrieve the JSON string by executing:

```
$webpart = $page.Controls | ? {$_.InstanceId -eq "<InstanceId of the Highlighted Content WP>"}  
$webpart.PropertiesJson
```

Reference:[Working with modern client-side pages using PnP PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/working-with-modern-clientside-pages-using-pnp-powershell#now-we-want-to-modify-another-page-homeaspx)

A sample from my test result:

```
{
    "displayMaps":{
        "1":{"headingText":{"sources":["SiteTitle"]},"headingUrl":{"sources":["SPWebUrl"]},"title":{"sources":["UserName","Title"]},"personImageUrl":{"sources":["ProfileImageSrc"]},"name":{"sources":["Name"]},"initials":{"sources":["Initials"]},"itemUrl":{"sources":["WebPath"]},"activity":{"sources":["ModifiedDate"]},"previewUrl":{"sources":["PreviewUrl","PictureThumbnailURL"]},"iconUrl":{"sources":["IconUrl"]},"accentColor":{"sources":["AccentColor"]},"cardType":{"sources":["CardType"]},"tipActionLabel":{"sources":["TipActionLabel"]},"tipActionButtonIcon":{"sources":["TipActionButtonIcon"]},"className":{"sources":["ClassName"]}},"2":{"column1":{"heading":"","sources":["FileType"],"width":34},"column2":{"heading":"Title","sources":["Title"],"linkUrls":["WebPath"],"width":250},"column3":{"heading":"Modified","sources":["ModifiedDate"],"width":100},"column4":{"heading":"Modified By","sources":["Name"],"width":150}},"3":{"id":{"sources":["UniqueID"]},"edit":{"sources":["edit"]},"DefaultEncodingURL":{"sources":["DefaultEncodingURL"]},"FileExtension":{"sources":["FileExtension"]},"FileType":{"sources":["FileType"]},"Path":{"sources":["Path"]},"PictureThumbnailURL":{"sources":["PictureThumbnailURL"]},"PreviewUrl":{"sources":["PreviewUrl"]},"SiteID":{"sources":["SiteID"]},"SiteTitle":{"sources":["SiteTitle"]},"Title":{"sources":["Title"]},"UniqueID":{"sources":["UniqueID"]},"WebId":{"sources":["WebId"]},"WebPath":{"sources":["WebPath"]}},"4":{"headingText":{"sources":["SiteTitle"]},"headingUrl":{"sources":["SPWebUrl"]},"title":{"sources":["UserName","Title"]},"personImageUrl":{"sources":["ProfileImageSrc"]},"name":{"sources":["Name"]},"initials":{"sources":["Initials"]},"itemUrl":{"sources":["WebPath"]},"activity":{"sources":["ModifiedDate"]},"previewUrl":{"sources":["PreviewUrl","PictureThumbnailURL"]},"iconUrl":{"sources":["IconUrl"]},"accentColor":{"sources":["AccentColor"]},"cardType":{"sources":["CardType"]},"tipActionLabel":{"sources":["TipActionLabel"]},"tipActionButtonIcon":{"sources":["TipActionButtonIcon"]},"className":{"sources":["ClassName"]}}
    },
    "query":{"contentLocation":5,"contentTypes":[1],"sortType":1,"filters":[{"filterType":1,"value":""}],"documentTypes":[99]},
    "templateId":4,"maxItemsPerPage":100,"hideWebPartWhenEmpty":false,"sites":[],"queryMode":"Basic","layoutId":"FilmStrip","dataProviderId":"Search","webId":"<webId>","siteId":"<siteId>"
}
```

You can also see the link [**here**](https://github.com/wobba/RandomFiles/blob/master/searchprops.json) for a sample json file
(original blog can be found via the first link from @Ganesh Sanap’s comment).