# Get JSON file contents into PnP PowerShell variable

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, pnp-powershell, json, highlighted-content-web-part

I am generating a web page in SharePoint Online with some web parts, using PnP PowerShell.

Now I am trying to set up a Highlighted Contents web part, that should display all documents in the site where the `Document Type` is "My Presentation".

I have found out what the JSON for the web part should look like (using the information in [Setting JSON Properties for Sharepoint Online Highlighted Content WP using PnP Powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/284135/setting-json-properties-for-sharepoint-online-highlighted-content-wp-using-pnp-p)). But it was a lot of JSON information so I put it in a JSON file (where I also got it formatted nicely).

What would be the code to get the contents of this JSON file in the variable `$myproperties` so that I can use it with `Set-PnPPageWebPart`?

```
Add-PnPPage -Name "Test"
      $page = Get-PnPPage -Identity "Test.aspx"
      
      $MyPresWP = Add-PnPPageWebPart -Page $page -DefaultWebPartType “ContentRollup” -WebPartProperties @{layoutId=”Card”;title=”My Presentations”}

      $MyPresId = $MyPresWP.InstanceId
      Set-PnPPageWebPart -Page Test -Identity $MyPresId -PropertiesJson $myproperties
```

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$myproperties = Get-Content -Path 'C:\path\to\your.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
```

OR

```
$myproperties = Get-Content -Path 'C:\path\to\your.json' -Raw
```

Comment: ```-Raw``` did the trick!

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!